# jTable didn't show knob to scroll horizontal

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, uiscrollview, jtable

I'm using a simple and the same technique on both program.

Left pic with knob in it and right pic without knob:

[image: left pic with knob in it and right pic without knob]

But, why the 2nd program (on the right) didn't have a knob in the scroll like the 1st program (on the left)?
The 2nd program also have many data and I need the knob to scroll down.
I already try to look the difference on both programs but didn't find one.

Here's my code:

```
 public UIForecasting() {
    initComponents();
    jTable2.setModel(new DefaultTableModel());
}
public void showdata() {
    DefaultTableModel tabelawal = new DefaultTableModel();
    tabelawal.addColumn("ID");
    tabelawal.addColumn("Jumlah Pemakaian");
    tabelawal.addColumn("Nilai Pemulusan Eksponensial");
    tabelawal.addColumn("Nilai Trend");
    tabelawal.addColumn("Hasil Peramalan");
    tabelawal.addColumn("MBA");
    tabelawal.addColumn("MSE");
    try {
        koneksi();
        sql = "SELECT * FROM tabelforecasting";
        Statement stat = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet res = stat.executeQuery(sql);

        while (res.next()) {
            tabelawal.addRow(new Object[]{""+ res.getString(1), res.getInt(2), res.getDouble(3), res.getDouble(4), res.getDouble(5),res.getDouble(6),res.getDouble(7)});

        }

        jTable2.setModel(tabelawal);            
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

Comment: You're asking a question about use of JScrollPane and yet inexplicably show **no code** that uses a JScrollPane -- why? Why hamstring your question like this? How can anyone tell what you may be doing wrong if you don't show the code most pertinent to your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not shown in your code (among other things) is your construction of the `JScrollPane`.  Probably something like:

```
JScrollPane scroller = new JScrollPane(jTable2);
```

This uses the 1 argument [JScrollPane constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JScrollPane.html#JScrollPane(java.awt.Component)), which has a default policy for the scrollbar:

> Creates a JScrollPane that displays the contents of the specified component, where both horizontal and vertical scrollbars appear whenever the component's contents are larger than the view.

If you always want to see the scrollbar(s), you should use one of the other constructors, or call `setVerticalScrollBarPolicy()` and/or `setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy()` and pass in the constant `ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS`.